# Easiest way to go to the closest closing bracket?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-auto-pairs

When I'm choosing an option from the autocomplete suggestions, it automatically puts my cursor in the following location:

```
function(|)
```

Then I type the value that I want, and in order to get out of the brackets (forward) I have to use the right arrow button, to yield:

```
function(value)|
```

Which is pretty inconvenient. Is there any better option?

EDIT: As mentioned in one of the comments, the `)` char can be used, but for me personally it's not more convenient. I would like to `map'`the return (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) key to function as the right arrow key in this specific situation.

Comment: If you're using "auto-pairs" plug-in, you should be able to type `)` when over a closing paren to get out of it. Doesn't that work for you? (Happy to turn this into an answer if it does work for you and was what you were actually looking for...)

Comment: Thanks for asking that. I forgot to mention that the solution you mentioned is available for me but from my subjective point of my personal comfort, this method for me is like using the arrow key for doing the job. I would like to "map" a key (perhaps even the return key) to do that in the mentioned particular case.

Comment: Auto-pairs has two default mappings that might also help: `<M-e>` for "fast wrap" and `<M-n>` to jump to the next closed pair. It seems to me the former might fit your use case? `<M-e>` typically means you need to press "Alt-e" to access it. Does that help? Not sure if mapping the Return key to get out of a pair would be feasible, since you often want line breaks within a pair and that's what Return does there, right?

Comment: Thanks again, @filbranden, I'm not sure how to use the "fast wrap". Can you specify the exact key strokes?

Comment: Take a look at [the full Readme for auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/blob/master/README.md). There's also Fly mode which you might find interesting. The original intent is that you'd type the closing bracket to get out of it and continue typing the expression. Other shortcut exists, the ones I mentioned earlier. If you want something different, please update the question to explain why these don't work for you and what you'd like to have instead...

Comment: If you're okay with remapping then something like `inoremap <whatever> <C-O>])<right>` will do this.

Comment: I would just go with `<C-o>a` if you are right next to the closing brace.

Comment: *"Can you specify the exact keystrokes?"* Yes, you can set variable `g:AutoPairsShortcutFastWrap` in your .vimrc, then the plug-in will use that (instead of the default of `<M-e>`) for "fast wrap" (assuming "fast wrap" behavior is what you really want here, sounds like it is...)

Answer (score 2):

I use `<esc>A`, it's 2.5 key strokes(0.5 for `shift`), it's not the shortest solution, but it's the most natural one if you are used to move around in normal mode. IMO, `<esc>` doesn't count as a keystroke.

`<c-o>A` works too, but I don't like it, I can't remember the last time i use [:h i_CTRL-O](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) .

You can also create a map for this:

```
inoremap <c-l> <right>
```

Change `<c-l>` to whatever key you like, I wouldn't use it, this kind of map is unnatural, it's also a burden to create, maintain and remember maps for trivial stuff.

Comment: why `<c-o>A` is not recommended, though?

Comment: @MaximKim It's just a habit, my fingers are used to it. Don't want to choose between `esc` and `c-o`, as brain need time to choose.

Comment: For me it is quite natural, use it all the time. Also I usually use `C-[` instead of `ESC` and it is next to `C-o` in terms of fingers used.

Answer (score 0):

### [vim-rsi](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi): Readline key bindings

The plugin vim-rsi by tpope provides readline style insert mode mappings. Following two might be of help in your case

> ```
>                                         *rsi-CTRL-E*
> <C-e>           Go to end of line.  Falls back to |i_CTRL-E| if
>                 already at the end of the line.  (|c_CTRL-E| already
>                 goes to end of line, so it is not mapped.)
>
>                                         *rsi-CTRL-F*
> <C-f>           Move forward one character.  Falls back to
>                 |i_CTRL-F| or |c_CTRL-F| at the end of the line.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack you could put in your .vimrc:

```
inoremap <Enter> <esc>:call DetectIfParens()<cr> i     // exits the insert mode and will return to it when the function ends

function DetectIfParens()
    let char = getline('.')[col('.')]                 // here we are in normal mode; check if the character to the right of the cursor is a closing parenthesis
    if (char==")")
        normal l                                      // puts the cursor after the parenthesis (sends the "l" key in normal mode)
    endif
endfunction                                          // after the function ends, you'll be in insert mode again
```